# How to get the values of the coefficients in the constraint matrix of an MILP in SCIP C++ interface

Tags: c++, linear-programming, scip

I am trying to get the coefficients of a variable in the constraint matrix of an MILP in SCIP. What I had been thinking was to loop through all the constraints that the variables appear in and somehow get the coefficients ( I am not sure how to). But is there a way to get all the coefficients in an `std::vector` by using any inbuilt functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of constraints do you have? If all your constraints are linear, you can include `cons_linear.h`, loop through all constraints and call `SCIPconsGetVars` and `SCIPconsGetVals`. 
This gives you all the variables that appear in your current constraint, as well as the coefficients.

What is it exactly that you want to do with these coefficients?

Comment: Yes! All the constraints are linear. Essentially each variable is a path that got added during column generation. I wanted to see which arcs are used. I already am keeping a list of the paths in a separate data structure but wanted to know if this was possible.

Comment: If you want to see which arcs are used, doesn't that mean that you are interested in the solution, rather than the coefficients?